# Scope of Local Variable

Tags: java, loops, variables, local

I'm still confused with scope of local variable
This code doesn't work because i in "i & n" is not resolved. I have identified it on for loops as int i =0. is it not enough? (This is adding nth character altogether our of string).

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++); {
        if (i%n == 0) {
            result = result + str.charAt(i);
        }
        else {
            result = result;
        }
    }
    return result;           
}
```

Comment: What's the point of that `else` statement?

Comment: You've got a semi-colon at the end of your `for` "header", before the brace. Get rid of it.

Comment: Did they answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Jon Skeet's answer-worthy comment, the semi-colon at the end of `for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++);` finishes the for-statement, and i is no longer in scope after the semi-colon.

Comment: ";" was major error in my code. I've got it and it was a great help!

Answer (score 1):

You are a few errors:

1. You can remove the else{ ... } part because you don't need it.
2. You have a extra ';' in your for loop statement.
3. There is a mistake on the index of the for loop. You need to do '**i less than**' str.length(), instead of i<=str.length(). Basically your for loop will try to access the full-length index of your character array, but actually it exceeds length. For example, the index for string 'hello' is 0,1,2,3,4. But "hello".length() is actually 5. If you try to access the 5th index of your string, you will see a '*java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException*' exception.

Also, you want the every Nth value, you want to do (i-1)%n. Again it is because of the index issue. Try to plug in parameters in your logic and use your pencil to write down the result, and you will see why.

And of course when i==0, you don't want (0-1)%n to happen. So skip i==0 by adding 'i!=0'.

Now, the following is the working code:

```
public static String everyNth(String str, int n) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if ((i-1)%n == 0 && i!=0) 
            result = result + str.charAt(i);
     }
    return result;           
}
```

Comment: It was a great help!! Thank you!!!